# How can I move custom menu inside mobile menu in magento2

Tags: magento2, menu

How can I move custom menu inside mobile menu in magento2?

Comment: Can  you please tell me ... on which section you want add?

Comment: i have ultimo theme so menu-top normally it is top-menu